# Angular: Why is my event handled twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have three controllers: main, product, customer. Controller A is part of my 'masterpage'. Controllers B and C are location dependent.

Controller main:

```
var MainController = function ($scope, $location, $rootScope, ToolbarService) {
    $scope.addClicked = function () {
        ToolbarService.onAddButtonClick();
    };
};

app.controller({ MainController: MainController });
```

product:

```
var ProductController = function ($scope) {

    $scope.$on('handleAddButtonClick', function () {
        alert('Add product');
    });
};
app.controller({ ProductController: ProductController });
```

customer:

```
var CustomerController = function ($scope) {

    $scope.$on('handleAddButtonClick', function () {
        alert('Add customer');
    });
};
app.controller({ CustomerController: CustomerController});
```

toolbarService:

```
app.service({
    ToolbarService: function ($rootScope) {
        return {
            onAddButtonClick: function () {
                $rootScope.$broadcast('handleAddButtonClick');
            }
        };
    }
});
```

When my location is `#/products` and the `addClicked` of main is invoked, I get the alert 'Add product' twice. Does anybody has a clue why this is?

Comment: are you sure you don't have two `ng-controller="ProductController"` in your page? Can you post the HTML?

Comment: @sh0ber Yes I am sure. When I search for `ng-controller="ProductController"` I get only one result..

Comment: When I set up your functions in a fiddle with my HTML, everything works as expected, so I think somehow you are getting two instances of the controller. Maybe that happens elsewhere in your code if not your HTML

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem was that I also had a controller declared in the routes. So I had configured a controller on my html page and one in the routes provider. This caused that everything executed twice..

Comment: doh, i had this problem

Comment: This helped me too, thank you. Hint: always be careful when declaring event handlers on object that may have multiple instances running at the same time.